# arm-none-eabi-gcc linking static library failed

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, arm, embedded

I am using "GNU Tools for ARMembedded processors (arm-none-eabi-gcc)" for compiling my projects

I am using eclipse IDE for compiling, I have three projects.

For example

- 'Project a' -- arm executable project
- 'Project b' -- static library
- 'Project c' -- static library

'Project b' has some function calls, these functions are defined in 'Project c'.
Also 'Project c' has some function calls, these functions are defined in 'Project b'.

When I link 'Project b' and 'Project c' with 'Project a' to create final executable, compiler says, the function calls in 'Project b' as well as in 'Project c' are undefined.

Also I have verified that the symbols were present in static library 'Project b' and 'Project c' using arm-none-eabi-nm tool, before it was linked to 'Project a'.

Whether the linker is removing those defined symbols and then linking the static library projects with 'Project a'. Then what can be done to stop linker from removing those symbols.

In my actual case there are three static libraries libMain_Project.a, libMAC_4E.a, libRTOS.a and I am linking this project this project using following syntax:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard
>   -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g -T "C:\Projects\K2MAC\802.15.4\k2-node\K2_MAC_4e\Platform\FRDMK64F\Linker\MK64F12\gcc\MK64FN1M0xxx12_flash.ld"
>   -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"MAC_4E.map" -o "MAC_4E.elf"  ./K2_MAC/MAC_Utilities/src/buffer_mgmt.o
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Utilities/src/memory_operations.o
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Utilities/src/queue_mgmt.o
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Utilities/src/timer_mgmt.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Management/PIB_Manager/pib_mgr.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Management/Frame_Manager/fm_ie_manager.o
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_Management/Frame_Manager/packetfunctions.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_API/src/mac_api_request.o
>   ./K2_MAC/MAC_API/src/mac_api_response.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/Lower_MAC/4E/LowerMacE.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/Higher_MAC_Primitives/HMAC_Beacon_Primitive.o
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/Higher_MAC_Primitives/HMAC_Data_Primitive.o
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/Higher_MAC_Primitives/HMAC_Scan_Primitive.o
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/Higher_MAC_Primitives/HMAC_Start_Primitive.o
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/Higher_MAC_Primitives/HMAC_TSCH_Primitive.o 
>   ./K2_MAC/Higher_MAC/src/hmac_task.o  ./main.o 
>   C:/Projects/K2MAC/802.15.4/k2-node/K2_MAC_4e/Project_files/Eclipse/Main_Project/Debug/libMain_Project.a
>   C:/Projects/K2MAC/802.15.4/k2-node/K2_MAC_4e/Project_files/Eclipse/Phy_Radio/Debug/libPhy_Radio.a
>   C:/Projects/K2MAC/802.15.4/k2-node/K2_MAC_4e/Project_files/Eclipse/RTOS/Debug/libRTOS.a

Then it is giving errors that the symbols are undefined even though the symbols are present in static library and this is verified using nm tool.

Comment: I see no evidence of `libMAC_4E.a` being linked, you are however linking `libPhy_Radio.a` which you did not mention.  Post the errors as well.